# sort query results by newest

Tags: query, sort

I wrote a query:

WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'portfolio_item', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-5));

which works and does what I want except it sorts the results from oldest to newest, and I want them to appear newest to oldest.  What can I add to the query parameters to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'portfolio_item', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-5, 'order' => 'ASC'));
```

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

for order parameters.

Hope that helps.

Comment: that seems like exactly what I am looking for so I don't know why it didnt work.
I tried 'order' => 'DESC'

and its of them changed anything.  The widget containing the query is still printing the portfolio_items starting from the beginning.

Comment: I added and 'order' => 'ASC' to the query parameters and it worked. thx

Comment: Sorry, wrong way round. Always confuses me. Glad that worked out for you.